# GMM weight matrix $W_n$ -- what does the index $n$ signify?

Tags: estimation, method-of-moments

The question is as in the title. The GMM estimator (in my Econometrics notes) is as follows:

$\hat \delta_{GMM}(W_n) = (S'_{xz} W_nS'_{xz})^{-1}(S'_{xz}W_ns_{xy})$

Comment: That $W_n$ is a function of the sample, and hence of the sample size, and so it will vary as sample size changes/increases.

Comment: Could you specify how it may be a function of the sample? An example would be great. My current (probably erroneous) understanding is that $W$ simply assigns relative weights to different moment conditions, so I don't see how it is a function of the sample. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: $W$ may be a constant matrix, may be not. When it is indexed by $n$ it means that it is constructed so as to be a function of the sample. The optimal choice of $W$ in terms of efficiency (estimator asymptotic variance) is a function of the sample, as a standard theorem proves which should also be  in your notes.

Comment: It is clear from the comments and an attempted answer that this question is inherently ambiguous and therefore unsuitable for this site.  If you can edit it to provide enough context to figure out the meaning of $n$, then we can vote to re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight matrix $W$ is unknown in this sample and must be estimated iteratively. The notation you've supplied for its estimation is consistent with the Newton-Raphson method where the change in iterative estimates is denoted by $\delta$. You've put the $\hat$ (hat) over that $\delta$, but it should really be over the $W$. As a rule, anything that's estimated (as indicated with hat notation), is implicitly subscripted with $n$.

Comment: I am not sure that $W$ is unknown -- isn't it the case that $W$ can be chosen arbitrarily by the researcher? Unless you're referring to the $W$ that produces the most efficient GMM estimator. If that's what you meant, then the estimator in my question is not necessarily the efficient one.

Comment: The *structure* of $W$ is known. The actual values must be estimated. The structure behind a $W$ could be exchangeable, auto-regressive, etc.